# Как проверить началось ли видео или нет?

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, jquery-ui, youtube-api

Имеется блок `.wrapper_group`, в нем `iframe` (youtube) `.video_groups` c видео и блок `.block_group` поверх него, при наведении на `.wrapper_group` скрывается `.block_group` и видно `.video_groups`, если мышку убрать с `.wrapper_group` то `.block_group` обратно покрывает `.video_groups`. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на воспроизведение `.video_groups` оставался даже при скрытии мышки с `.wrapper_group`?

```
$('.wrapper_group').hover(function () {
$(this).children(".block_group").css('visibility', 'hidden');
}, function () {
$(this).children(".block_group").css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Надо проверять состояние плеера, а для этого получать ссылку на него после старта API YouTube. В примере `video-head` - это id элемента `iframe`.

```
var playerVideoHead;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    playerVideoHead = new YT.Player('video-head', {
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}
```

Изменение состояния плеера делается так:

```
togglePlayer(playerVideoHead);

function togglePlayer(player) {
    if (typeof player.getPlayerState == "undefined") return;
    var state = player.getPlayerState();

    if (state == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
        player.playVideo();
    } else {
        if (state == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            player.pauseVideo();
        }
    }

}
```